# How to create binary distributions of applications with cabal (the tool) or stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, cabal-install, cabal-new

I've written an application in Haskell and it's starting to become slightly useful to users. However my application isn't targeted at technically adept folks, let alone Haskell developers, so building my application from source isn't really something I can expect them to do.

So to make my application available to my users, I would like build the application myself, put its executable, data files, dependencies, the dependencies' data files, required licensing information and other required files into one archive and put that archive up onto a website. Now users can download that archive, unpack it and have everything required to run my application.

The process I described above seems like a fairly common way to distribute binaries of applications to me. However, I can't figure out what tools to use or how to configure them to build my application into a binary distribution described above.

Cabal (the library) seems to have the features that are required for this. Usual `Setup.hs` scripts (without cabal (the tool) or stack as wrappers) support options such as `--prefix` and `--enable-relocatable` that let you install a package to the given prefix and compile them in such a way as to ensure that data files can still be located if the prefix (as a whole) is moved somewhere else.

But using the raw `Setup.hs` has the downside that it doesn't handle automatically installing dependencies. And since many decently sized Haskell applications will have hundreds of dependencies (or at least mine does), configuring and building each of them by hand isn't really feasible.

The obvious solution to the problem of installing dependencies would be to use a wrapper tool such as cabal (the tool) or stack, since they are specifically made to deal with the problem of large dependency trees. However, they all seem to have problems preventing me from building my application as a binary distribution:

- `stack build` doesn't have the options `--prefix` or `--enable-relocatable` and instead always installs to `.stack-work` and `~/.stack`.
- `cabal v2-*` has the options `--prefix` and `--enable-relocatable` but seems to ignore them entirely and instead always installs to `dist-newstyle`  and `~/.cabal`.
- `cabal v1-*` seems to do what I want for very simple cases. However, for more complicated cases it produces obscure build failures, where GHC complains about not finding modules from dependencies and cabal complains about partially installed packages. But even putting these failures aside, using legacy commands for a new workflow doesn't seems like a good idea in general.

So, since I seem to be out of luck with these tools, what other tools can i use to build Haskell applications into binary distributions? Or maybe one of the tools I listed actually does what I want and I'm just using it the wrong way?

Some limitations in scope:

- For now I'm mostly interested in builds for Windows, but solutions for other platforms would be interesting as well.
- When I'm talking about dependencies, I mostly mean Haskell dependencies (i.e. Cabal packages). Solutions which also bundle foreign C dependencies would be interesting, but that's not a strict requirement.

Comment: I think there's not a really great way at the moment. Does Windows have a chroot-alike?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use `cabal repl` like this (from the directory with `your-package.cabal`):

```
$ cabal repl -b Cabal
...
ghci> :load /path/to/Setup.hs
...
ghci> :main configure --prefix=/my/prefix
...
ghci> :main build
...
ghci> :main copy --destdir=/my/dest/dir
...
```

That should take care of building all your dependencies, while still being able to use `Setup.hs`.

I think this can still cause issues if your dependencies use `data-files`.

Comment: Yes, I remember that I used a similar workaround in the past. Like you say: it works as long as the dependencies don't have data-files. But since it doesn't install the dependencies into the prefix it also doesn't install the licenses of the dependencies (somethind cabal usually does) into the prefix. Since some licenses (such as the GPL) require you to supply a license along with compiled code, this might not be ok from a legal point of view.

Comment: Also, it's just awkward as heck.